# Magento 2 customer grid inline edit how to disable specifc column

Tags: magento2.3.5

[image]

Can you please help me on that.Any solution for the above query?

Comment: custom column or core grid column??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable it by overriding **ui_component** file `customer_listing.xml`.

> path: Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_listing.xml

try below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="customer_columns" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
        <column name="email" sortOrder="40">
            <settings>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>false</editorType>
                </editor>
            </settings>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

After this clear your cache.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about your own component, then you can open the grid and learn from Magento itself. Or search here, many articles are available.

Here is an example link: [Set inline edit disable for certain field](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/250819/set-inline-edit-disable-for-certain-field)

In case you want to disable core module. You can follow my steps here:

I tried to overwrite via xml but it doesn't work. So If anyone has a solution using layout, kindly let me know.

My solution uses Javascript.

1. You need to overwrite the column. Here I take `email` as an example. Use the code below in your own `customer_listing.xml` file

Just to make use of the component, here in this case: `Vendor_Module/js/inline_edit`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="customer_columns" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
        <column name="email" component="Vendor_Module/js/inline_edit" />
    </columns>
</listing>
```

2. In your `Vendor_Module/js/inline_edit` file, paste the following content

```js
define([
    'Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column'
], function (Column) {
    'use strict';

    return Column.extend({
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            this.editor = {};
            
            return this;
        },
    });

});
```

Comment: check my answer you can do it by xml also.

Comment: @RakeshVarma Thanks! Work like a charm. How did you find the `false` value to put there?

Comment: in `Magento_Ui/js/grid/editing/record.js`  file there is a condition like this `if (_.isObject(field) && field.editorType)`  to create editor filed so I have pass `false`